# Vector ParametricNDSolve and FindRoot interaction

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, parametric-functions

This question came out of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199458).

I have a set of differential equations, written in vector form. I'm only interested in the value of these at the endpoint, and so I use `ParametricNDSolve`, asking it to only return that function of the vectors. 
This works fine on its own, and is slightly quicker than asking for the whole solution to be returned:

```
Clear[test];
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 0, 0}}; test = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == A.Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4]}, 
  Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
First@AbsoluteTiming[test /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];]
(* 0.037914 *)
```

However, if I try to use this same function in `FindRoot`, it now takes much longer to evaluate at the same points afterwards:

```
Clear[test];
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 0, 0}}; test = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == A.Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4]}, 
  Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
Quiet[FindRoot[test[q], {q, 3}]];
First@AbsoluteTiming[test /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];]
(* 0.24924 *)
```

Which is 6 times longer than it took to do exactly the same calculation. Note that the function definition is identical, just the use of the function in the `FindRoot` has changed (which is also much slower than just getting the entire interpolation functions out and then calculating only the part I need).

Can anyone explain what is going on? I get the same timings on 11.3 and 12.0 on my mac.

Comment: It somehow has to do with the "ParametricSensitivity". When you call `FindRoot` derivatives are computed from the parametric function and possibly stored (cached?) with the object. I do not know the exact details of why this would make the evaluation solver but you can avoid it by setting `Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> None}` in `ParametricNDSolve`. This is not exactly my home turf, so if you need an answer and no one here knows that you may want to consider sending this to support.

Comment: @user21, thank you

Comment: @KraZug Think of an example in which `FindRoot[]` finds the root, and not just works in vain.

Comment: I reported this to Wolfram Support and they agreed it is a bug. The two fixes are potential workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add a method, then the time is reduced by an order. In this example, the `test-1000` has a root

```
Clear[test];
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 0, 0}}; test = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == A.Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4]}, 
  Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
Quiet[FindRoot[test[q] - 1000, {q,0,1}, Method -> "Secant"]];
First@AbsoluteTiming[test /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];]
(*0.0341673*)
```

Compare without method and without `FindRoot[]`

```
 Clear[test];
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 0, 0}}; test = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == A.Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4]}, 
  Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
Quiet[FindRoot[test[q] - 1000, {q, 3}]];
First@AbsoluteTiming[test /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];]

(*0.271661*)

 Clear[test];
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 0, 0}}; test = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == A.Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4]}, 
  Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
First@AbsoluteTiming[test /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];]

(* 0.0395219 *)
```

With the option `Method -> "Secant"` code works even faster than without `FindRoot[]`.If we use the option `Method -> "AffineCovariantNewton"`, then the time increases:

```
 Clear[test];
A = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {q, 0, 0, 0}}; test = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{Y'[x] == A.Y[x], Y[0] == Table[1, 4]}, 
  Y[4].Y[4], {x, 0, 4}, q];
Quiet[FindRoot[test[q] - 1000, {q, 1}, 
   Method -> "AffineCovariantNewton"]];
First@AbsoluteTiming[test /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];]

(* 0.298559 *)
```

Consequently, Newton's method (the default method) can slow down the code in this combination.

Comment: Thank you, this is another workaround to go with the `ParametricSensitivity` option. I suspect that the slight speed increase in `Method -> "Secant"` will be due to the caching of the initial value of `q=3`.